# Set timeout Running continously

Tags: javascript

Please See the below code runs at the rate of 60 frame per second..If any button is clicked isjump will be set to true and below code start excuting.What i am trying is i need to exit out jump() function after 1 second.I tried setout like below...but still lines inside settime out is running indefinitely..Please help me.

What i am actually trying is exit  jump function after 1 second.

```
function jump() {
    if (isjump) { 
        player.posx +=10;
        console.log("jumping"); //this line is stopped after 1 second
        setTimeout(function () {
            isjump = false;
            console.log("stopped"); //but this line is continuing 
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I also tried clearTimeout still no use.

```
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function () {
    isjump = false;
    console.log("stopped");
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
}, 500);
```

Edit : For those who think this jump function is called continously...yea it is called continously...For every frame game character position will be updated.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: it's not a problem of setTimeout. You are for some reason calling the jump() function indefinitely. Paste the code where you are calling jump.

Comment: I do use requestanimationFrame...

Comment: What is `Window.timeoutHandle`

Comment: Just was a default comment, I saw "fps" and thought of requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: yea it should run indefinetely for game to work !! but why console.log("jumping"); is stopped if jump is running continously

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : my mistake typo..still it wont work

Comment: In what scope are you using `isjump`?

Comment: @Vishnu - It seems that somewhere else in your code is calling `jump` continuously.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : yea jump should be called continously , only then my game player position will be updated in fps!! i just posted sample code here

Comment: @Vishnu - Hmm. One thing that comes to my mind is scoping, but since the two `isjump`s shares the same scope, this should not be an issue.

Comment: yea isjump is global variable !! i have defined that outside already

Comment: Guys I solved the solution , please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found The solution..I solved it by running the settimeout function only once inside a loop.

```
var once = true;
function jump() {
    if (isjump) { 
        player.posx +=10;
        console.log("jumping"); //this line is stopped after 1 second
        if(once)
        {
            setTimeout(function () {
                isjump = false;
                console.log("stopped"); //but this line is continuing 
            }, 1000);
        }
        once = false;
    }
}
```